# Why do downvotes on questions take 2 rep

Tags: discussion

As stated, whenever I post a question (I'm not very good at wording them), it usually gets downvotes. Now when this happens, for every downvote, I lose two reps instead of one. Why is this?
If this happens, surely all it does, as it has to me, is deter people from asking more questions.

Comment: Because it costs 2 rep not 1.

Comment: Yes, if a post of yours is downvoted, it costs you 2 points. It doesn't matter if it is a question or an answer. For you to downvote *some other answer* costs you 1 point, but that is *something different*.

Comment: Instead of getting deterred from asking more questions, people should take downvotes as a signal to improve their posts.

Comment: It deters people from asking more poorly worded questions.

Answer (score 7):

Every upvote gets you 5 or 10 rep. Given that your upvotes are supposed to outweigh your downvotes, the occasional 2 rep loss doesn't really hurt all that much.

That is, unless you're getting downvoted pretty regularly. But in that case the cost is not the problem that needs to be addressed. It's the quality of the content you contribute. Downvotes need to hurt a little to poke you into changing your ways.

So if the downvotes inspire you to ask better questions, that's great. If you can't or won't improve and the downvotes deter you from asking more questions, I'm afraid that's a net positive as well.