# Why question downvote is -2 reputation?

Tags: discussion

With some google-fu I've found a statement ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291828/1997232)):

> Given that your upvotes are supposed to outweigh your downvotes, the occasional 2 rep loss doesn't really hurt all that much.

Why upvotes suppose to outweight downvotes?

Why `-2` and not `-5` (same as upvote amount)?

I was thinking about having two questions with **same** score (doesn't really matter which one), where one is upvoted/downvoted by ten people and another by hundereds and suddenly second one profit the asking guy with much much more reputation gain. Why?

Maybe I am rather missing some important part of upvoting? I upvote very rarely and probably only questions which I find *nice* (with something special) or *interested in answer too*. Most of my upvotes went to answers.

Comment: Very relevant Uber-Meta post: [Should the weight of downvotes be increased?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7322)

Comment: Specifically, the motivation for this is [given in Jeff’s answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased/42763#42763).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, but those are about answers. I think my question is different. Or not? Same thoughts? So `-2` is to *not hammer* new users too much? I think new users will take even `-1` too serious.

Comment: No, those are about questions. Question upvote reputation *was* changed, at some point. See [Should the weight of question upvotes be reduced?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/42769)

Comment: @Sinatr *I think new users will take even -1 too serious* - you hit the nail on the head right there :) So if you make it -5, people may have a nervous breakdown.

Comment: @Gimby, you will rarely see questions with `-20` score disregards of view counts, I think it's because as soon as it become negative *enough* new visitors feels *mercy* and don't downvote more. With `-5` penalty people will downvote less (I mean that *mercy trigger level*). And there will be less *poor soul* upvotes.

Comment: @Sinatr The meta effect proves differently, I think more that questions rarely go below -20 because they simply don't get enough eyeballs to make it drop that far.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Reputation change* for voting was never meant to be balanced, only the post score is.

The creator of the site, Jeff Atwood, [considered increasing the penalty of downvotes to -5 to match the +5 rep gain from upvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased), back in July 2009 (a little under a year after the site started). This was at a time when question upvotes gained you +10 points, same as answer upvotes, so even then there was no intention of making the reputation changes be *equal*.

The idea was rejected nearly a year later, in March 2010, and Jeff's [arguments against raising the downvote penalty to -5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42763) were two-fold:

- downvote penalties were *meant* to be cosmetic, yet at a mere -2 are still taken very seriously by those that receive them. A higher reputation cost would greatly amplify this effect, as users are quite attached to their reputation points. And it'd make it harder on the *voters* to cast votes that they know will 'damage' the receiver more, not something we can use when we want people to use their downvotes *more*, not less.
- if the penalty is raised to -5, then perhaps the paltry cost of -1 to cast a downvote should be raised too, to match (Jeff was talking about -2 or -3 to cast votes), which would discourage downvoting even more. That's really not what we'd want.

Note that since that discussion, two things changed: on the day Jeff wrote his answer rejecting raising the penalty, he proposed that question upvotes [should be lowered from earning you +10 to +5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42769/should-the-weight-of-question-upvotes-be-reduced), and that change went into effect a few days after. And another year later, in May 2011, [downvotes on questions became free](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free).

Jeff also [explained the Stack Overflow philosophy of voting costs on his blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/09/the-value-of-downvoting-or-how-hacker-news-gets-it-wrong/):

> In building Stack Overflow, we realized the intrinsic informational value of full range post scores. Downvotes give you the critically important ability to **distinguish between the good, the bad, and the ugly**. Without downvotes, how can you possibly tell the difference between a post that is harmless but uninteresting, and one that is actually wrong or harmful? Sure, it stings a bit to get downvoted. I’ve been downvoted myself on Stack Overflow. And each time, it makes me pause. But that’s *good*! That’s *necessary*! You have to believe there are potential consequences for every post you make — both good and bad. [...]
>
> The problem isn’t downvotes, per se, but encouraging responsible downvoting. That’s why on Stack Overflow, we do it this way:
>
> - Upvotes add **10** reputation to the post author
> - Downvotes remove **2** reputation from the post author, *and **1** from your reputation*
>
> ***The trick here is that downvotes are mostly informational***. The cost of a downvote to the users’ reputation (or karma in Slashdot/Reddit parlance) is quite low.

Italicised bold emphasis mine.

The important part here is that the Stack Overflow system of voting both up and down captures the right level of information to help judge the usefulness of a post, but that doesn't mean we need to remove reputation at the same rate that we add reputation.

Comment: Thanks, now with the whole story explained the linked earlier in comment post makes total sense to me. Though due to changes second part become irrelevant, the first one is still valid: downvotes are cosmetic and we don't want to penalize bad questions more than they are already. Still, my rephrased question is this: why question poster with more downvotes still **gain** reputation? Imagine a question with total score `-1` (1 upvote, 2 downvotes), why this still give `+1` reputation??? Shouldn't it be negative somehow because **more** people think it's bad?

Comment: @Sinatr: why should a user be penalised for even trying? They could still be taught how to use the site correctly, and encouraged to continue and ask another question *and do better*. The psychological effect is already there with -2, we don't need to make them feel entirely dejected. We have enough problems with users using fraudulent extra accounts to upvote their own posts to try to get out of question bans or bypass the limitations by asking on a new account. If downvotes penalised that much, we'd chase away those that would actually ask good questions in the future, too.

Comment: Good argument with "dejected". So the user is rewarded for posting "not too bad" questions. Of course he will have to improve to gain more, but he is already *acceptable* good if 1 out of 3 people think his question is good (1 upvote per 2 downvotes). And most of reputation should be obtained anyway by posting answers, not by asking "not so good" questions.

Comment: @Sinatr: note that if a user continues to post bad questions, then an automatic post ban kicks in, anyway.

Comment: @Sinatr What is the user is new and doesn't know how the site works, It isn't fair if he loses some hard earned reputation. That happened to me, when I started out. I gained 3 reputation, then people downvoted, and I got only 1. It wasn't very fair towards me. I suppose other users will feel the same thing if this happens to them. They probably don't know how it works, as most people don't read the FYI page. I know I didn't, at least. Also, when a question is incorrect, sometimes the user is either a noob at programming or can't restate it because of some language defiencies. Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: It's funny, I have the feeling I'm the only one there who takes the downvote more seriously than the negative reputation itself. I mean, if I get the downvote to begin with, it means I must have done something the wrong way, right? Unless it's on a meta, of course.

Comment: People are hesitant to downvote... not because you lose rep, but because your rep is no longer a perfect multiple of 5/10.... the only options are to either cast 5 of them, or none :D

Comment: @coldspeed I'd never thought about that before but now I won't be able to *un*-think about it.